# What is preferred method to use newer CSS3 selectors in IE 8 and 7?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-selectors, cross-browser

What is preferred method to use newer CSS3 selectors in IE 8 and 7? Fireofx, Chrome, Safari and Opera has better CSS selectors support compare to IE.

Is there a lightweight way to enable support for all secetors in IE. I'm not asking about feature detection (Modernizr) and to emulate CSS3 effects (PIE) in IE.

I'm asking to use all selectors in IE . So when I will be writing CSS I can optimized  my css and html wisely use new selectors.

I already use Modernizr (including HTML Shim), jQuery almost in all projects. I know about IE7.js but I want to know if there is any other better alternative because IE7.JS sometime break the layout when we add it existing websites.

Comment: IE9 supports a good deal of CSS3 selectors too. The main problems are IE7 and IE8.

Comment: @BoltClock - right. I modified the question

Comment: @BoltClock - But according to this list some selectors not supported in IE9 http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc351024.aspx

Comment: Sounds like you know about all the best tools already. The unfortunate truth is that there's no way to simply make everything work perfectly with zero drawbacks. You should be able to do most of what you need with CSS2 selectors. Fill in the gaps with javascript/HTC for older browsers.

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: Yes, not all of them. Still not as much of a problem though, IMO... in fact, even IE7 and IE8 support advanced attribute selectors and the general sibling combinator `~` pretty well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) is designed specifically to do this.

Comment: it seems not a standalone library. and it support all selector if if use with NM watcher. but I think as I'm already using jQUery so I will use it with jquery  and will only use those selector which Selectivizri is making possible with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

I was a bit hesitant when I first started using CSS3 selectors because of browser-compatibility, but I find that when I use them it's only in very obscure situations where I am trying to achieve a pixel-perfect layout. If it turns out that I need to use them for something that is more important, I always turn to throwing on a few more classes in my markup, rather than relying on Javascript.

Some day, maybe we can comfortably use CSS3 selectors without worrying about people supporting them. [We've already seen the downfall of one bad browser](http://www.ie6countdown.com/), so it's really only a matter of time.

Here's a related article on the subject that I like: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement